# Ejecutar comando desde java

Tags: java, linux, compilador

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
String java(){
    try {
        Process process;
        String file="If";
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -verbose  If < codigo.txt ",null,new File(ruta));
        //process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        String output = "";
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {

            output += line + "\n";
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Output: "+output);
        buf.close();
        return output;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Intento ejecutar un comando para compilar desde java otro código java, el problema es al momento de usar `<` para ingresar información de entrada a la clase se traba todo y no continúa nada, entonces tengo que matar el proceso

Comment: codigo.txt está en el classpath?. De todos modos, deberías usar [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html](http://example.com)en ves de Runtime.exec()

Comment: Supongo que hay otras maneras de compilar código Java desde un programa pero ¿cómo le estás pasando el código al compilador? ¿No se trata de pasarle a javac (no java) un archivo para que lo compile?

Comment: Si, codigo.txt está en el mismo path

Comment: El código (al menos en consola) es el If.class y de entrada de datos recibe un código.txt

Answer (score 2):

Quizá el problema es que estas con MS Windows 10 y el entorno de ejecución de comando a cambiado a PowerShell donde el < esta reservado pero de momento No tienen ningún cometido. La sintaxis correcta es:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Get-Content codigo.txt | java -verbose  If ",null,new File(ruta));
```

El equivalente a dirigir en CMD un fichero (codigo.txt) a la entrada estándar de un comando con
comando < codigo.txt

En powershell queda
Get.Content codigo.txt | comando

Comment: Responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, por favor edita y explica